# IEnumerable, List, or ??? for returning ADO.NET collections?

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, ienumerable

If we use ADO.NET for data access, how should we return a collection of an object?  I'm reading that DataTables are NOT the best way (also because they're untyped).  In the old days I know you could to an XSD to type them, but that's still not  a proper collection of an object I believe.

We'll have our class (e.g. Employee) and properties, etc so a single object will be returned as, e.g., and Employee object.  But should a collection be an IEnumerable?  If so, are we to iterate over the DataTable in the class and add to list one at a time?  That seems cumbersome (also requiring a List at that point I think).

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Do you have considered to use an ORM?

Answer (score 2):

> If so, are we to iterate over the DataTable in the class and add to list one at a time?

No, forget DataTable completely. You don't populate a DataTable - you go straight for the list; either via an ORM (EF, NHibernate, etc), or via a tool like "dapper":

```
string region = ...
var customers = conn.Query<Customer>(
    "select * from Customer where Region=@region",
    new { region }).ToList();
```